# Can any sigma algebra be generated by a ring which is strictly contained in the sigma algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$\newcommand{\scrD}{\mathcal{D}}$
$\newcommand{\scrR}{\mathcal{R}}$
$\newcommand{\scrF}{\mathcal{F}}$
Situating definitions.

> **Definitions:** Let $\Omega$ be a set.
>
> 1. A collection of subsets $\scrR$ of $\Omega$ is called a **ring** in $\Omega$ if it is closed under unions and set differences.
> 2. A collection of subsets $\scrF$ of $\Omega$ is called a **sigma-algebra** if it contains the empty-set, is closed under complements, and closed under countable unions.
> 3. Let $\scrD$ be an arbitrary collection of subsets of $\scrD$, then $\sigma(\scrD)$ is the minimal $\sigma$-algbera generated by $\scrD$; i.e the intersection of all sigma algebras which contain $\scrD$.

My question comes from the uniqueness of measures theorem.

> **Theorem:** Let $\scrD$ be a ring in $\Omega$ and let $\mu_1,\mu_2$ be two measures defined on $\sigma(\scrD)$ which agree on $\scrD$. Then if $\scrD$ satisfies the finite measure covering condition; i.e there is a sequence $(D_n)$ of sets in $\scrD$ for which $\Omega = \cup_1^\infty D_n$, and further $\mu_1(D_n) < \infty$ for all $n \geq 1$, then $\mu_1=\mu_2$ on all of $\sigma(\scrD)$.

**Question:** If we just have a random sigma algebra say $\scrF$, is there always some proper ring which generates $\scrF$?

Because it seems like that would be useful as it pertains to the theorem. I know you could just use $\scrF$ itself as it's a ring, but then the statement is trivial. Thanks in advance for the clarification.

Comment: So your question seems to be really whether any sigma algebra $\mathcal F$ can be generated by a ring of sets $\mathcal R$ which is a strict subset of $\mathcal F$.

Comment: Exactly, I thought to add context just in case. I can edit if it's off topic.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. If $\Sigma$ is an arbitrary sigma algebra in $\Omega$, you mean the candidate ring is what?

Comment: @Henry: the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{\varnothing\}$ contains $\varnothing$ and its complement, $\Omega$, so it is equal to that $\sigma$-algebra. Likewise, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\varnothing$ is $\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$, so your assertion that they do not "generate the $\sigma$-algebra" is incorrect.